# Java code returns only one object from test method

Tags: java

I want to generate some test data using this Java code:

```
@GetMapping("/volumes")
    public ResponseEntity<List<DashboardDTO>> getProcessingVolumes() {

        return ResponseEntity.ok(testDate());
    }


    public List<DashboardDTO> testDate() {



        List<DashboardDTO> list = null;

        for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
            list = new ArrayList<>();
            DashboardDTO obj = new DashboardDTO();
            obj.setAmount(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(20, 500 + 1));

            LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.now().minus(Period.ofDays((new Random().nextInt(365 * 70))));
            Date date = Date.from(localDate.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());

            obj.setDate(date);
            obj.setNumber_of_transactions(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(300, 5000 + 1));
            list.add(obj);
        }
        return list;
    }
```

But when the code is run only one object is generated. Do you know where I'm wrong? I want to generate 10 test objects.

Comment: I appreciate the quick accept!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
        list = new ArrayList<>();
```

You create a **new** result list during each loop. So the last loop creates another list for the last entry!

Simply move that line `list = new ArrayList<>();` **in front** of the loop, so that it gets executed just once.

Your code creates 11 new lists, each one with one entry, and you return that last list object. Instead: create one list and add your 11 elements and then return that single list.

Answer (score 3):

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
        list = new ArrayList<>(); //(Fix here)--> resetting your list everytime causing only single object to return.
```

Try to initialize only single time.

```
List<DashboardDTO> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
        DashboardDTO obj = new DashboardDTO();
        obj.setAmount(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(20, 500 + 1));

        LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.now().minus(Period.ofDays((new Random().nextInt(365 * 70))));
        Date date = Date.from(localDate.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());

        obj.setDate(date);
        obj.setNumber_of_transactions(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(300, 5000 + 1));
        list.add(obj);
    }
    return list;
```